# Function to solve problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is the question:

For which $A, B$ the function $y=Ax+B$ solves

$y'=sin(y-x)$?

I started by taking $y'$ of the function, to get $A$.  I then plugged the function into the equation:

$A=sin(Ax+B-x)$

Here I got stuck.  Am I allowed to subtract $Ax$ and $x$ to leave just $sin(b)$?  Otherwise, I'm not sure where to go from here.

Also, if the equation was $y'=1.001sin(y-x)$, how would the solution change?  I don't understand the significance of $1.001$.  Thanks.

Comment: Is xin supposed to be sin?

Comment: Note that $Ax-x=x(A-1)$, the terms do not cancel unless $A=1$.

Comment: This seems like a somewhat odd question, what motivates it?

Comment: Yes, xin was supposed to be sin.  I apologize.  Also thank you for the comments, I was out and did not have a chance to respond.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got stuck at
$A=\sin(Ax+B-x)$.

For this to be true,
the two sides have to be equal
for all $x$.

The left side is a constant.

The right side can take on
many different values
unless the argument of $\sin$ is constant.
This means that
$Ax+B-x=C$
for some constant $C$.

There are two parts of
$Ax+B-x$ - the constant part
($B$) and the linear part
($Ax-x$, which is the same as
$x(A-1)$).

For $Ax+B-x$ not to vary,
the linear part must be zero.
This can only happen if $A=1$.

Putting $A=1$ in the equation,
it becomes
$1 = \sin(B)$.

The maximum value of the $\sin$ function
is $1$, and this occurs at
$2\pi n+\pi/2$
for any integer $n$. 
If you are looking at values from
$0$ to $2\pi$,
the only value of $B$
that makes $\sin(B) = 1$
is $B = \pi/2$.

Therefore the solution is
$A=1$ and $B=\pi/2$.

Comment: Thank you, the problem makes much more sense now.  I didn't exactly know the rules and how to play with the function.

Comment: Oh, also, I still don't understand the significance of 1.001 in the second part.  Is there something special I need to do about that?

Comment: @user91971:  try following through the derivation with the multiplier $1.001$  What changes?  You still have a constant on the left.

Comment: I worked through the problem with 1.001 and got $\frac{1}{1.001}=sin(B)$?  Is this correct?  I have a feeling I did something wrong.  It doesn't feel different enough from the last answer.